# While loop doesn't work/loops forever | Beginner question

Tags: python, loops, random, while-loop

Below is my attempted solution to this problem: The top prize in a lottery is won by matching three numbers between 1 and 30 to three random numbers drawn in the same order. When a ball is drawn it is put back into the machine before another ball is drawn. There are always 30 balls in the machine before a ball is drawn and a player may choose the same ball more than once. A draw takes place once a week. Write a function that takes three numbers as parameters, draws three random numbers between 1 and 30 and returns the number of weeks it took to win the jackpot. (E.g. Numbers chosen: 17, 12, 25 must match: ball one is 17, ball two is 12, ball three is 25.)

My attempt:

```
import random

chosen = []
for i in range(0, 3, 1):
  chosen.append(input("Please input your lucky number: "))

drawn_numbers = []
count = 0
week_count = 0

print("Your chosen numbers are: {}, {}, {}".format(chosen[0], chosen[1], chosen[2]))

while count != 3:
  for i in range(0, 3, 1):
    random_number = random.randint(1, 30)
    drawn_numbers.append(random_number)
  
  for i in range(0, 3, 1):
    if drawn_numbers[i] in chosen:
      count += 1
    
  week_count += 1
  drawn_numbers = []

print("It took you {} weeks to win.".format(week_count))
```

For some reason the while loop just ignores the `count += 1` part and loops randomly generated drawn_numbers lists forever.

Obviously there is something wrong with my loop, but I can't see it D:

Some advice on how to make that loop work would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: The values in `chosen` are strings, not integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - welcome to the world of Python!

You have several mistakes:

- The [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function returns a [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) and not an [int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int). Meaning, the comparison you try to do implicitly in `if drawn_numbers[i] in chosen` would **never** be true, thus `count` is always 0 and you got yourself an infinite loop.
- Assuming that you've fixed the mistake above, you still have a chance of `count` never hitting 3 at the evaluation of the loop. Consider the following scenario:

  1. A user enters the numbers `[1, 2, 3]`
  2. The `drawn_numbers` are `[1, 2, 4]`
  3. Thus, `count` will be now `2`
  4. The `while` condition is `count != 3` is `True` and thus the loop continues.
  5. The numbers are drawn again are `[1, 2, 4]`
  6. The `count` will be now `4`
  7. From now on, `count` can only increase and will never be equal to `3`!

  Do you see where this is going? Try to reset the `count` at the start of loop (inside)!
- > a lottery is won by matching three numbers ... in the **same order**

  But the comparison you've implemented only looks for **existence** in the list instead of comparing element by element.

---

So, a working (not written in the most Pythonic way) version will be:

```py
import random

chosen = []
for i in range(0, 3, 1):
    chosen.append(int(input("Please input your lucky number: ")))  # notice the int cast

drawn_numbers = []
count = 0
week_count = 0

print("Your chosen numbers are: {}, {}, {}".format(chosen[0], chosen[1], chosen[2]))

while count != 3:
    count = 0  # notice that count is reset here 
    
    for i in range(0, 3, 1):
        random_number = random.randint(1, 30)
        drawn_numbers.append(random_number)
    
    for i in range(0, 3, 1):
        if drawn_numbers[i] == chosen[i]:  # notice that we compare the elements in the same location
            count += 1

    week_count += 1
    drawn_numbers = []

print("It took you {} weeks to win.".format(week_count))
```

---

If you're interested, here is a more Pythonic way:

```py
import random

chosen = [int(input("Please input your lucky number: ")) for _ in range(3)]
print(f'Your chosen numbers are: {chosen}')

matched = False
week_count = 0

while not matched:
    drawn_numbers = [random.randint(1, 30) for _ in range(3)]    
    matched = drawn_numbers == chosen
    week_count += 1

print(f"It took you {week_count} weeks to win.")
```

In which you might find several features that might be new to you but I strongly encourage you to master them:

1. [List comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)
2. `range(3)` is equivalent to `range(0, 3, 1)`
3. [Formatting string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)
4. The `==` operator actually compares two lists element by element!

---

Funny side note: Running this code without the order restriction results in much less weeks to wait to win the lottery :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your if-statement ever becomes true?

One thought is, that chosen might includes string-values as numbers. Try running:

```
print(type(chosen[0]))
```

This should be a int. Fix it by:

```
chosen.append(int(input("Please input your lucky number: ")))
```